# Dynamic UI based on Large JSON response / Web UI based on JSON Schema implementation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json, lightning-community, lightning-web-components, ui

I'm dealing with a complex problem and need expert opinion for selecting a right approach.

In short,

1. Need to render a Dynamic UI based on JSON returned by an external system.
2. Each user selection leads to an HTTP callout.

**PROBLEM SUMMARY**

> Need a scalable solution that leverages one of the various
>   implementations of ***Web UI generation based on JSON Schema***  here 
>   https://json-schema.org/implementations.html.
>
> Please share your experience or thoughts on utilizing one of the above
>   implementations of Web UI Generation vis-a-vis Salesforce Roadmap. 
>   [JSONForms](http://ulion.github.io/jsonform/playground/?example=fields-color), in particular seemed interesting.

**APPROACHES Considered**:-

1. **SERVER Callout** : Make callouts using Apex , parse JSON , create dyanamic UI by using createComponent()
2. **BROWSER Callout** : Make callouts from  Javascript , parse JSON , render UI .

2nd approach is preferred considering each form has about 200 UI fields which translates to 200 API callouts subject to governor limits for synchronous calls. [Speeding tickets](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/11/avoiding-the-concurrent-request-limit-via-synchronous-callout-optimization.html) for 10 concurrent users will be hit anytime.

**SECURITY**

Below are some thoughts.

1. External System will ONLY allow GET calls for Lightning JS
2. Short Expiration Auth Token for above calls to External System
3. Rate Limiting at External System

*Please comment on security aspects.*

**BUSINESS BACKGROUND**
We deal with complex configurable products. Product data and the configuration rules cannot be stored and maintained in Salesforce.
[image]

**SAMPLE JSON**

```
    {
  "summary": [
    {
      "description": null,
      "id": "FRM1",
      "image": "",
      "name": "***GLOBAL OPTIONS***",
      "children": [
        {
          "dataType": "A",
          "description": "",
          "image": "",
          "length": 5,
          "name": "BRAND",
          "segment": "BRAND",
          "value": "Isuzu",
          "valueImage": "",
          "valueName": "Isuzu",
          "isHeading": false,
          "mandatory": true,
          "pn": ""
        },
        {
          "dataType": "A",
          "description": "",
          "image": "",
          "length": 3,
          "name": "PRODUCT LINE",
          "segment": "PRD.LINE",
          "value": "MAG",
          "valueImage": "",
          "valueName": "Magna",
          "isHeading": false,
          "mandatory": true,
          "pn": ""
        },
        {
          "dataType": "A",
          "description": "",
          "image": "",
          "length": 15,
          "name": "STYLE",
          "segment": "STYLE",
          "value": "FLAT",
          "valueImage": "",
          "valueName": "Flat",
          "isHeading": false,
          "mandatory": true,
          "pn": ""
        },
        {
          "dataType": "A",
          "description": "",
          "image": "",
          "length": 7,
          "name": "SPECIE",
          "segment": "SPECIE",
          "value": "RUST",
          "valueImage": "",
          "valueName": "Rustic",
          "isHeading": false,
          "mandatory": true,
          "pn": ""
        },
        {
          "dataType": "A",
          "description": "",
          "image": "",
          "length": 10,
          "name": "FINISH",
          "segment": "FINISH",
          "value": "CARB",
          "valueImage": "",
          "valueName": "Carbon",
          "isHeading": false,
          "mandatory": true,
          "pn": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you have a few misunderstandings about how Lightning works? You might want to also break your question up in to several parts, it will be easier to address.

Comment: Expanding on that, I think there are several misunderstandings on how Salesforce itself works. You can store anything in Salesforce, it's just data. Up to you on if you want to write a custom SPA for the data hygiene and config maintenance eschewing all the tooling in Salesforce.

Comment: thanks for response ! To elaborate on the data part  I cannot substantiate the millions of rows of rules which are maintained in external system , not all of them are in database. The external system is mainframe based.

Comment: so the pressing question that I am seeking opinion on, is for utilizing JSONForms http://ulion.github.io/jsonform/playground/?example=fields-color for creating UI form/page in Lightning . thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current comments, I'd like to direct you to use another technology, something like [React with SLDS baked](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com) in or something like [External Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_external_objects.htm).

I'm not sure they fit your use case but it may provide you further tools to consider.

With your data responsible for generating UI elements outside of Salesforce, Aura/LWC does not seem to be a good fit initially because they do assume some level of data existing in your Salesforce Schema for technologies such as `@wire`. External Objects may or may not gap that.

Otherwise, you would be leveraging Salesforce as a huge REST API broker between your external system and the UI layer.

Comment: External Objects won't fit my use case . 

*Standard Schema*
TRANSACTION DATA  : Order - > OrderItem 
MASTER DATA    : Product2 

*Schema including External Objects* 
TRANSACTION DATA  : Order - > OrderItem -> OrderItemConfig_ExtObj__c 
MASTER DATA    : Product2 -> Product2Config_ExtObj__c

However, I am avoiding to store or display "Product Configuration" data (which is accessible as JSON via http callout)for reasons explained above - there is no business reason + we don't want to re-create another ERP in CRM. 

Thanks much for direction - will explore React and post the outcomes!

Comment: @user66468 did you see how external objects makes the rest callout for you?

Comment: I did use external objects for some other use cases for referrential display. Used it after wrapping source in Odata..